# Need some help for choosing the replication type

Tags: sql-server

My target is to create a replication process for the following

Please suggest which type of replication is suitable for this architecture, See the image below

[image: Please click here for image]

Comment: What are you trying to achieve ? This will help suggest better solution for your scenario. Also SQL server version and edition will be useful to know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the simple view, this pretty much looks like Transactional Replication from {Publisher1, Publisher2, Publisher3} to Subscriber.

I assume that Subscriber includes the `Staging DB`.  Therefore, as the `Staging DB` is updated it can, in turn, become a publisher using Transactional Replication to {Subscriber1, ..., Subscriber5}.

Of course, depending on the way data is maintained, you might need to use Merge Replication instead.

Paul Ibison has a brief article that discussed the differences in republishing with Transactional or Merge Replication at: http://www.replicationanswers.com/Republishing2005.asp

The big issue is being sure that you clearly understand which sources of data are **authoritative**, how the data flows (and what happens to it in the `Staging DB`), et cetera.